# how does the odometry (imu+encoder) publish its data to gmapping?

Tags: navigation, odometry, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am able to get my odometry working (with IMU and encoders readings). But how do i actually publish the relevant data to gmapping? Is the gmapping file actually subscribing any data from the odometry?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67406/how-does-the-odometry-(imu+encoder)-publish-its-data-to-gmapping?/) by [Andrick](https://answers.ros.org/users/5397/andrick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-07-15

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2018-06-07**:
Hı, Mr. @Andrick . Coul you please help me how to merge ımu andencoder data?

**Comment by [kallivalli](https://answers.ros.org/users/42408/kallivalli/) on 2019-09-17**:
how did you get odometry working can you share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To answer questions of this nature, it is always good to refer to the package itself: [gmapping subscribed topics](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gmapping#Subscribed_Topics)

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2013-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

Basically as Weiin said the Gmapping link shows that Gmapping is subscribed to tf/tfMessage to get its odometer information.

You need to publish the odometer information as both a nav_msgs/Odometry and a tf/tfMessage. A good tutorial explaining this can be found here

http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom

---

Originally posted by [HenryW](https://answers.ros.org/users/3316/henryw/) with karma: 140 on 2013-07-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on 2013-07-16**:
You do not need the odometry message for gmapping. It gets that data through the tf. (You do however, need the odometry message for the navigation stack.)

**Comment by [HenryW](https://answers.ros.org/users/3316/henryw/) on 2013-07-17**:
Yes sorry Weiin is correct, Gmapping does not need it itself :D

**Comment by [Andrick](https://answers.ros.org/users/5397/andrick/) on 2013-07-17**:
Alright thanks! I'll have to read more about the tf then! :)